# RedHen Registration: where is the display settings?

Tags: users

I'm using the RedHen module for registration to an event.

I created the registration type and a content type Event that has a field "Registration".
For what I read, when one visualize a instance of a content Event it should appear the fields of the registration type but it isn't. In the description it says that depends on the "display settings" but when I create registration type I didn't see an option like that.

What can be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a pretty specific support question about one specific module. You may have a better chance at getting an answer when you post a support request in the [Redhen issue queue](https://drupal.org/project/issues/redhen?categories=All) on drupal.org.

Comment: While this question is probably pretty on-topic here, I'm afraid @marcvangend is right. Only 591 sites currently report using this module. This is pretty low count, and it means that encountering people who know it here is pretty improbable. On the other hand their issue queue does not seem heavily overloaded. Of course if you will get your answer there, don't hesitate to post it here as a self-answer :)

Comment: Yeah, I resolve my problem with the display but I still need to do more things with redhen, so let see how it goes. Thank you for leaving the link of redhen support.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a break and with my mind a bit clearer.
The display settings don't depend of the registration type, they can be found in "manage display" of the content type (in my case "Event"). Only that no matter what display one choose it will always appear a tab for "registration", but I think this can be manage with the css.